# Vue component doesn't update on route URL parameter change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So I have a component which executes code once it's mounted like this:

```js
mounted(){
  axios.get('/markers/' + this.username)
    .then(response => {
      this.markers = response.data.markers
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

And I get the username like this:

```js
username: this.$route.params.username
```

however, if I change the URL parameter, the username doesn't update so my AXIOS call doesn't update my markers. Why is this happening?

Comment: You might need to use Dynamic Route Matching, see if [this post](/a/54167162/3634538) helps.

Comment: Did you set the `key` prop on the `<router-view />` component? i.E. `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />`? This might be needed for the `mounted` hook to trigger when switching between view components.

Comment: What do you mean by "The username doesn't update". I don't see any code here that updates the username property, could you include the whole file? What does your `data()` function look like, why not just call `/markers/' + this.$route.params.username` Is there any errors happening? This needs more information please.

Comment: @swonder, he meant that if you go to route `/markers/john`, and then you navigate to `/markers/smith`, it will still show **john**

Comment: Well since the username is set based the username param in the URL, I assumed it would update automatically if I change the url, however, it doesn't. Nothing else in my code is relevant to my issue. Exactly what ljubadr said.

Comment: Have you thought of putting a watcher on the username property to see if it's being updated? Then when it's updated you could run a function that makes the GET request rather than on mounted. Does it re-mount the component if it's the exact same component?

Comment: @r0skar's solution should be the correct accepted answer. Using a watcher is not quite the best as it doesn't force the component to rerender on params change. So it could lead to some unwanted behaviours ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is simple, even thought the URL is changing the component is not, VueJS is basically reusing the component and therefore not calling the mounted() method again.

Usually you can just setup a watcher and refactor a bit your code

```js
methods: {
    fetchData(userName) {
        axios.get('/markers/' + this.username)
        .then(response => {
            this.markers = response.data.markers
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
},
watch: {
    '$route.params': {
        handler(newValue) {
            const { userName } = newValue
   
            this.fetchData(userName)
        },
        immediate: true,
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added the immediate true option and removed the mounted() hook

Comment: Pretty much what I said in my comment, I didn't think the component would "mount" again if you're changing to the exact same component. This confirms that. Nice work.

Comment: I'm curious, will the watch `handler()` fire if user goes to completely different route?

Comment: Not if the new route renders another component